# Adding more tableViews as subview on my main scrollView depending on a UISwitch state works only after application relaunches

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, uiswitch

UPDATED BELOW!

I have a UI structure with a horizontal scrollView nesting 5 tableViews – each representing a day of the week. I have added a UISwitch to add weekend to the week, so when the user switches it on, two more tableview-subviews are added to the scrollView. So far so good, but the switch change only takes effect, when I relaunch the application. Looks like ViewDidLoad() makes it happen, but nothing else. I added a Bool variable called isWeekOn. Its state is managed from viewDidLoad:

```
isWeekendOn =  UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "switchState")
    dayTableViews = fiveOrSevenDayTableViews()
```

where fiveOrSevenTableViews() is a closure returning the array of tableviews with the proper count and dayTableViews is my local array variable.

```
lazy var fiveOrSevenDayTableViews: () -> [DayTableView] = { 
    if self.isWeekendOn == false {
        return [self.mondayTableView, self.tuesdayTableview, self.wednesdayTableview, self.thursdayTableView, self.fridayTableView]
    } else {
        return [self.mondayTableView, self.tuesdayTableview, self.wednesdayTableview, self.thursdayTableView, self.fridayTableView, self.saturdayTableView,self.sundayTableView]
    }
}
```

I added a didSet property observer to isWeekendOn and that also calls setupViews(), where the number of tableviews is also decided by calling fiveOrSevenTableViews closure .

```
var isWeekendOn: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            print("LessonVC IsWeekendon: ",isWeekendOn)
           dayTableViews = fiveOrSevenDayTableViews()
             setupViews()
            print("didset daytableviews", fiveOrSevenDayTableViews().count)

        }
    }
```

Where my setupViews() looks like:

```
   func setupViews() {
    setupScrollView()


    let numberOfTableViews = CGFloat(dayTableViews.count)
    let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: fiveOrSevenDayTableViews())
    print("setupViews stacview subviews count", stackView.arrangedSubviews.count)
    stackView.axis = .horizontal
    stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
    scrollView.addSubview(stackView)
    setupStackViewConstraints(stackView, numberOfTableViews)
}
```

And setupScrollView():

```
 private func setupScrollView() {
    let numberOfTableViews = CGFloat(dayTableViews.count)
    print("setupScrollview dableviews", numberOfTableViews)
    scrollView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.bounds.width, height:0)
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width * numberOfTableViews, height: 0)
    view.addSubview(scrollView)
    setupScrollviewConstraints()
}
```

All the print statements are called properly, so I am wondering, why the changes actually do not take effect real time, and instead working only relaunch.

What I tried:

As @maniponken suggested,  i made a function which looks like:

```
func readdStackView(_ stackView: UIStackView) { stackView.removeFromSuperview() 

    setupViews() }
```

than I call this within the isWeekendOn didSet observer. Didn't work out unfortunately.

UPDATE:

Actually when I put *anything* in my isWeekendon didSet observer, doesn't work! For example changing my navigationBar backgroundColor...etc Everything is reflecting on console though, in the print statements! Those  functions also take effect at relaunch only.I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

UPDATE2:

Removing the tables works without problem with a local UIButton! My Problem is the following though: I have a settings view controller, which has a switch for setting 5 or 7 table views. Realtime update does not work with that switch, only with le local button, triggering an @objc func. I still need that settings panel for the user though!

Comment: Maybe you need to call `.removeFromSuperView()` on all items and then call add them again

Comment: @maniponken, it sounds like a good idea and i made a function which looks like: func readdStackView(_ stackView: UIStackView) {
        stackView.removeFromSuperview()
        setupViews()
    }   than I call this within the isWeekendOn didSet observer. Didn't work out unfortunately.

Comment: If the table views are simply subviews of the scroll view, this is a very straightforward process. You add or subtract views, enable and disable the appropriate constraints, and call `layoutIfNeeded()` on the appropriate superview (the scroll view in this case). I also notice you're setting the content size of the scroll view manually which you should not be doing--the constraints of the scroll view's subviews will do that.

Comment: So all you need to do is add the 5 table views to the scroll view with the appropriate constraints where the left-most table view's leading anchor is pinned to the leading edge of the scroll view and the right-most table view's trailing anchor is pinned to the trailing edge of the scroll view (this is how content size is dynamically calculated). Then when the switch is enabled, add the two extra table views, disable Friday's trailing edge constraint and now pin Sunday's trailing edge constraint to the trailing edge of the scroll view. And call `layoutIfNeeded()` and that's it.

Comment: @bsod, it sounds very promising! Sorry for being such a beginner, but how do I disable a constraint in code?

Comment: Also: should i remove all and re-add proper count of tableviews every time switch is changed, as @DonMag suggested?

Comment: I don't work with Interface Builder so I can only comment on this programmatically. But what I would do is make the key constraints instance properties. For example, `lazy var fridayTrailingAnchor = fridayTableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor)`, enable it in `viewDidLoad` (for example), `fridayTrailingAnchor.isEnabled = true`, and then toggle it through the switch with the other key constraints, and call `scrollView.layoutIfNeeded()`.

Comment: @bsod i have a scrollView pinned on view edges, scrollView has a stackView as subView, also pinned to view edges. DayTableViews are arranged subViews of the stackView.  As stackViews handle subviews on their own, probably I shouldn't care much about the constraint of the tableViews. The are just .fillEqually.

Comment: Note: I am not using Interface Builder in this project either.

Comment: What's the purpose of the stack view? Why not just add the tables directly to the scroll view? There are only 5 or 7 objects in play here.

Comment: The purpose of using stackView is to avoid a ton of constraint calculation every time, when my tableviews array is changing. The problem seems to be that stackView only changes its subviews count on console, and the result is taking effect only after relaunch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have solved the problem.

UPDATE: The main reason I had to set up NotificationCenter for this matter, is that I used UITabBarController to add SettingsVC to my app instead of presenting it modally. Details below.

//Skip this part for answer
My main problem – as it turned out – was that my UISwitch was on a separate vc, called SettingsViewController. 
This switch supposed to do the tableview-adding and removing on my main vc. I tried with delegate protocols, targeting shared instance of settingsVC, nothing worked, but adding a local button for this – which is definitely not what I wanted.
 Then I read about NotificationCenter! 
I remembered it from Apples App Development For Swift book,I read last year, but forgot since. 
**// So the Anwswer**

After I set my constraints correctly based on the great hint of @DonMag, I set up **NotificationCenter** for my SettingsViewController, posting to my Main VC.

```
class SettingsViewController: UITableViewController {

   private let reuseID = "reuseId"

    lazy var switchButton: UISwitch = {
        let sw = UISwitch()
        sw.addTarget(self, action: #selector(switchPressed), for: .valueChanged)
        sw.onTintColor = AdaptiveColors.navigationBarColor
        return sw
    }()

    static let switchNotification = Notification.Name("SettingsController.switchNotification")

    var isOn = Bool() {
        didSet {


NotificationCenter.default.post(name:SettingsViewController.switchNotification, object: nil)
    }
}
 @objc func switchPressed(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(sender.isOn, forKey: "switchState")
    self.isOn = sender.isOn   
}
```

then in the mainVC:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        scrollView.delegate = self

        view.backgroundColor = .white

        isWeekendOn = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "switchState")
// The Solution:
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleRefresh), name: SettingsViewController.switchNotification, object: nil)

        dayTableViews = fiveOrSevenDayTableViews()
        print("daytableviews count ", dayTableViews.count)
        scrollView.delegate = self

        editButtonItem.title = LocalizedString.edit
        navigationItem.title = localizedDays[currentPage]

        setupNavigationBar()
        setupButtons()
        setupTableViews()
        setupViews()
        isWeekendOn == true ? setupCurrentDayViewFor_7days() : setupCurrentDayViewFor_5days()

    }
```

then here in mainVC's  `@objc func handleRefresh() { }` i am handling the removal or addition!

UPDATE:

in SettingsVC:

```
     static let switchOnNotification = Notification.Name("SettingsController.switchOnNotification")
   static let switchOffNotification = Notification.Name("SettingsController.switchOffNotification")

    var isOn = Bool() {
        didSet {

        }
        willSet {
            if newValue == true {
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name:SettingsViewController.switchOnNotification, object: nil)
            } else if newValue == false {
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name:SettingsViewController.switchOffNotification, object: nil)
            }
        }
    }
```

in viewDidLoad in mainVC:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleAddWeekendTableViews), name: SettingsViewController.switchOnNotification, object: nil)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleRemoveWeekendTableViews), name: SettingsViewController.switchOffNotification, object: nil)





@objc func handleAddWeekendTableViews() {

        [saturdayTableView, sundayTableView].forEach {
            stackView.addArrangedSubview($0)
            dayTableViews.append($0)
    }
}

@objc func handleRemoveWeekendTableViews() {
   manageCurrentPage()
    dayTableViews.removeLast(2)
    [saturdayTableView, sundayTableView].forEach {
        $0.removeFromSuperview()
          }

}
```

This one is actually working!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it's not a stackview but it works for adding (and removing) tableviews to a ViewController.
This method is not using Storyboards

In your viewcontroller, containing the tableview

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class SevenTableviews: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    let tableView1: UITableView = {
        let tv = UITableView()
        tv.backgroundColor = .white
        tv.separatorStyle = .none
        return tv
    }()

    let tableView2: UITableView = {
        let tv = UITableView()
        tv.backgroundColor = .white
        tv.separatorStyle = .none
        return tv
    }()

    let tableSwitch: UISwitch = {
        let switchBtn = UISwitch()
        switchBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(switchTables), for: .touchUpInside)
        return switchBtn
    }()

    var isTableTwoShowing = false

    let reuseIdentifier = "DaysCell"
    var days = ["monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday"]
    var weekendDays = ["saturday", "sunday"]


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupTableview()
    }

    func setupTableview() {
        tableView1.dataSource = self
        tableView1.delegate = self
        tableView1.register(DaysTableviewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        view.addSubview(tableView1)
        tableView1.anchor(top: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: view.centerYAnchor, right: view.rightAnchor)

        if isTableTwoShowing == true {
            tableView2.dataSource = self
            tableView2.delegate = self
            tableView2.register(DaysTableviewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
            view.addSubview(tableView2)
            tableView2.anchor(top: view.centerYAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, right: view.rightAnchor)
        }

        view.addSubview(tableSwitch)
        tableSwitch.anchor(bottom: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingBottom: 24, paddingRight: 12)


    }

    @objc func switchTables() {

        if tableSwitch.isOn {
            isTableTwoShowing = true
            setupTableview()
        } else {
            isTableTwoShowing = false
            tableView2.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if tableView == tableView1 {
            return days.count
        } else if tableView == tableView2 {
            return weekendDays.count
        } else {
            return 0
        }

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier) as! DaysTableviewCell

        if tableView == tableView1 {
            cell.dateLabel.text = days[indexPath.row]
            return cell
        } else {
            cell.dateLabel.text = weekendDays[indexPath.row]
            return cell
        }

    }
}
```

in your tableviewCell-class:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class DaysTableviewCell: UITableViewCell {

    let identifier = "DaysCell"

    let cellContainer: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        view.backgroundColor = Colors.boxBack
        view.setCellShadow()
        return view
    }()

    let dateLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)
        return label
    }()

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        setupViews()
    }

    func setupViews() {

        selectionStyle = .none

        addSubview(cellContainer)
        cellContainer.anchor(top: topAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: bottomAnchor, right: rightAnchor, paddingTop: 4, paddingLeft: 8, paddingBottom: 4, paddingRight: 8, height: 35)

        cellContainer.addSubview(dateLabel)
        dateLabel.anchor(top: cellContainer.topAnchor, left: cellContainer.leftAnchor, bottom: cellContainer.bottomAnchor, right: cellContainer.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 4, paddingLeft: 8, paddingBottom: 4, paddingRight: 8)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

I am using the same cell class for both tableviews but you can decide yourself how you want to do this.

Also, my constraints are set with an extension i found from a tutorial once:

```
extension UIView {

    func anchor(top: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor? = nil, left: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor? = nil, bottom: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor? = nil, right: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor? = nil, paddingTop: CGFloat? = 0, paddingLeft: CGFloat? = 0, paddingBottom: CGFloat? = 0, paddingRight: CGFloat? = 0, width: CGFloat? = nil, height: CGFloat? = nil) {

        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        if let top = top {
            topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: top, constant: paddingTop!).isActive = true
        }

        if let left = left {
            leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: left, constant: paddingLeft!).isActive = true
        }

        if let bottom = bottom {
            if let paddingBottom = paddingBottom {
                bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottom, constant: -paddingBottom).isActive = true
            }
        }

        if let right = right {
            if let paddingRight = paddingRight {
                rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: right, constant: -paddingRight).isActive = true
            }
        }

        if let width = width {
            widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: width).isActive = true
        }

        if let height = height {
            heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: height).isActive = true
        }
    }

}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Unfortunately this code does not reflect my structure. My problem is still the same, removing  removing, readding the tableviews do not work on the fly. Only after restart. As I mentioned the removing works on "paper", meaning that in the print statements i get the proper array sizes. My UI just does not refresh accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Couple notes:

- You don't need to re-create / re-add your stack view ever time the switch gets changed. Add it in `viewDidLoad()` and then add / remove the "DayTableViews"
- Use constraints for your stack view inside your scroll view, instead of calculating `.contentSize`.
- Probably want to use an array of your "Day Tables" rather than having individual `mondayTableView`, `tuesdayTableView`, etc... vars.

Here's an example you can work from. I used a simple `UIView` with a centered label as a simulated "DayTableView" - should be pretty clear. Everything is via code - no `@IBOutlet` or `@IBAction` - so to test this, create a new project, add this code, and assign the startup view controller to `AddToScrollViewController`:

```
//
//  AddToScrollViewController.swift
//
//  Created by Don Mag on 11/15/19.
//

import UIKit

class DayTableView: UIView {

    // simple UIView with a centered label
    // this is just simulatig a UITableView

    let theLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.textAlignment = .center
        v.backgroundColor = .yellow
        return v
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit() -> Void {

        addSubview(theLabel)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            theLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor),
            theLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor),
        ])

    }

}

class AddToScrollViewController: UIViewController {

    let theSwitch: UISwitch = {
        let v = UISwitch()
        return v
    }()

    let scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let v = UIScrollView()
        v.backgroundColor = .orange
        return v
    }()

    let stackView: UIStackView = {
        let v = UIStackView()
        v.axis = .horizontal
        v.distribution = .fillEqually
        v.spacing = 16
        return v
    }()

    let mondayTableView: DayTableView = {
        let v = DayTableView()
        v.theLabel.text = "Monday"
        return v
    }()

    let tuesdayTableView: DayTableView = {
        let v = DayTableView()
        v.theLabel.text = "Tuesday"
        return v
    }()

    let wednesdayTableView: DayTableView = {
        let v = DayTableView()
        v.theLabel.text = "Wednesday"
        return v
    }()

    let thursdayTableView: DayTableView = {
        let v = DayTableView()
        v.theLabel.text = "Thursday"
        return v
    }()

    let fridayTableView: DayTableView = {
        let v = DayTableView()
        v.theLabel.text = "Friday"
        return v
    }()

    let saturdayTableView: DayTableView = {
        let v = DayTableView()
        v.theLabel.text = "Saturday"
        return v
    }()

    let sundayTableView: DayTableView = {
        let v = DayTableView()
        v.theLabel.text = "Sunday"
        return v
    }()

    var dayTableViews: [DayTableView] = [DayTableView]()

    lazy var fiveOrSevenDayTableViews: () -> [DayTableView] = {
        if self.isWeekendOn == false {
            return [self.mondayTableView, self.tuesdayTableView, self.wednesdayTableView, self.thursdayTableView, self.fridayTableView]
        } else {
            return [self.mondayTableView, self.tuesdayTableView, self.wednesdayTableView, self.thursdayTableView, self.fridayTableView, self.saturdayTableView,self.sundayTableView]
        }
    }

    var isWeekendOn: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            print("LessonVC IsWeekendon: ",isWeekendOn)
            dayTableViews = fiveOrSevenDayTableViews()
            setupViews()
            print("didset daytableviews", fiveOrSevenDayTableViews().count)

        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // for each of these views...
        [theSwitch, scrollView, stackView].forEach {
            // we're going to use auto-layout
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        }

        // for each of these views...
        [mondayTableView, tuesdayTableView, wednesdayTableView, thursdayTableView, fridayTableView, saturdayTableView, sundayTableView].forEach {
            // we're going to use auto-layout
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            // constrain widths to 160 (change to desired table view widths)
            $0.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 160.0).isActive = true
            // give them a background color so we can see them
            $0.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        }

        // add the (empty) stack view to the scroll view
        scrollView.addSubview(stackView)

        // add the switch to the view
        view.addSubview(theSwitch)

        // add the scroll view to the view
        view.addSubview(scrollView)

        // use safe area for view elements
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide

        // we need to constrain the scroll view contents (the stack view, in this case)
        // to the contentLayoutGuide so auto-layout can handle the content sizing
        let sg = scrollView.contentLayoutGuide

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            // put switch in top-left corner
            theSwitch.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 12.0),
            theSwitch.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 12.0),

            // constrain scroll view 12-pts below the switch
            // and leading / trailing / bottom at Zero
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theSwitch.bottomAnchor, constant: 12.0),
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor),
            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),

            // constrain the stack view to the scroll view's contentLayoutGuide
            // with 8-pts padding on each side (easier to see the framing)
            stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sg.topAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sg.bottomAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sg.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sg.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0),

            // constrain height of stack view to height of scroll view frame,
            // minus 16-pts (for 8-pt padding)
            stackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.heightAnchor, constant: -16),

        ])

        // add a target for the switch
        theSwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(switchChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)

        // set based on saved state in UserDefaults
        isWeekendOn = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "switchState")

    }


    @objc func switchChanged(_ sender: Any) {
        // switch was tapped (toggled on/off)
        if let v = sender as? UISwitch {
            // update state in UserDefaults
            UserDefaults.standard.set(v.isOn, forKey: "switchState")
            // update the UI
            isWeekendOn = v.isOn
        }
    }

    func setupViews() {

        // first, remove any existing table views
        stackView.arrangedSubviews.forEach {
            $0.removeFromSuperview()
        }

        // get the array of 5 or 7 table views
        let a = fiveOrSevenDayTableViews()

        // add the table views to the stack view
        a.forEach {
            stackView.addArrangedSubview($0)
        }

        print("setupViews stacview subviews count", stackView.arrangedSubviews.count)

    }

}
```

Scrolled to the right with the "weekend switch" off:

[image]

Scrolled to the right immediately after turning the "weekend switch" on:

[image]

---

**Edit**

Here is a slightly different (bit more efficient) approach. Instead of adding / removing table views, simply show / hide the Saturday and Sunday tables. The stack view will automatically handle the scroll view's content size.

Full updated example:

```
//
//  AddToScrollViewController.swift
//
//  Created by Don Mag on 11/15/19.
//

import UIKit

class DayTableView: UIView {

    // simple UIView with a centered label
    // this is just simulatig a UITableView

    let theLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.textAlignment = .center
        v.backgroundColor = .yellow
        return v
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit() -> Void {

        addSubview(theLabel)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            theLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor),
            theLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor),
        ])

    }

}

class AddToScrollViewController: UIViewController {

    let theSwitch: UISwitch = {
        let v = UISwitch()
        return v
    }()

    let scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let v = UIScrollView()
        v.backgroundColor = .orange
        return v
    }()

    let stackView: UIStackView = {
        let v = UIStackView()
        v.axis = .horizontal
        v.distribution = .fillEqually
        v.spacing = 16
        return v
    }()

    let mondayTableView: DayTableView = {
        let v = DayTableView()
        v.theLabel.text = "Monday"
        return v
    }()

    let tuesdayTableView: DayTableView = {
        let v = DayTableView()
        v.theLabel.text = "Tuesday"
        return v
    }()

    let wednesdayTableView: DayTableView = {
        let v = DayTableView()
        v.theLabel.text = "Wednesday"
        return v
    }()

    let thursdayTableView: DayTableView = {
        let v = DayTableView()
        v.theLabel.text = "Thursday"
        return v
    }()

    let fridayTableView: DayTableView = {
        let v = DayTableView()
        v.theLabel.text = "Friday"
        return v
    }()

    let saturdayTableView: DayTableView = {
        let v = DayTableView()
        v.theLabel.text = "Saturday"
        return v
    }()

    let sundayTableView: DayTableView = {
        let v = DayTableView()
        v.theLabel.text = "Sunday"
        return v
    }()

    var isWeekendOn: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            print("LessonVC IsWeekendon: ",isWeekendOn)
            setupViews()
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // for each of these views...
        [theSwitch, scrollView, stackView].forEach {
            // we're going to use auto-layout
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        }

        // for each of these views...
        [mondayTableView, tuesdayTableView, wednesdayTableView, thursdayTableView, fridayTableView, saturdayTableView, sundayTableView].forEach {
            // we're going to use auto-layout
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            // constrain widths to 160 (change to desired table view widths)
            $0.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 160.0).isActive = true
            // give them a background color so we can see them
            $0.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
            // add them to the stack view
            stackView.addArrangedSubview($0)
        }

        // add the stack view to the scroll view
        scrollView.addSubview(stackView)

        // add the switch to the view
        view.addSubview(theSwitch)

        // add the scroll view to the view
        view.addSubview(scrollView)

        // use safe area for view elements
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide

        // we need to constrain the scroll view contents (the stack view, in this case)
        // to the contentLayoutGuide so auto-layout can handle the content sizing
        let sg = scrollView.contentLayoutGuide

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            // put switch in top-left corner
            theSwitch.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 12.0),
            theSwitch.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 12.0),

            // constrain scroll view 12-pts below the switch
            // and leading / trailing / bottom at Zero
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theSwitch.bottomAnchor, constant: 12.0),
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor),
            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),

            // constrain the stack view to the scroll view's contentLayoutGuide
            // with 8-pts padding on each side (easier to see the framing)
            stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sg.topAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sg.bottomAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sg.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sg.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0),

            // constrain height of stack view to height of scroll view frame,
            // minus 16-pts (for 8-pt padding)
            stackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.heightAnchor, constant: -16),

        ])

        // add a target for the switch
        theSwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(switchChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)

        // set based on saved state in UserDefaults
        isWeekendOn = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "switchState")

        // update the switch UI
        theSwitch.isOn = isWeekendOn

    }


    @objc func switchChanged(_ sender: Any) {
        // switch was tapped (toggled on/off)
        if let v = sender as? UISwitch {
            // update state in UserDefaults
            UserDefaults.standard.set(v.isOn, forKey: "switchState")
            // update the UI
            isWeekendOn = v.isOn
        }
    }

    func setupViews() {

        // show or hide Sat and Sun table views
        saturdayTableView.isHidden = !isWeekendOn
        sundayTableView.isHidden = !isWeekendOn

    }

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this solution did not work in my project either. Removing and readding table views with for loops or individually do not take effect until relaunch.

Comment: No, sorry, I tried to adapt the most relevant parts from your code in my environment. I will give it another look.

Comment: I corrected the layout problem, avoiding the calculated scrollView content size. .Updated the whole auto layout according to Apple Docs. and some more up-to-date articles about layoutContentGuide and frameLayoutGuide. The layout works much better now. However my problem is the same: when i am updating stackView.arrangedSubViews.count, the result is only visible on the console, not in my application. Only after relaunch.

Answer (score 0):

Why don’t you make a horizontal collection view instead of the normal scroll view. It would be easier to call reloadData whenever you want to add or delete a cell (and of course each cell is a tableView)